# Why am I getting a "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error on strings

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python to query my DB and printing out the values line by like as follows:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT id, name FROM playlists")
lists = cursor.fetchall()

for index, list in lists:
    print("{0} - {1}".format(list['id'], list['name']))
```

However this beings back the following error when executed:

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What is `list`? It seems it's a string, and as the error says, that's not the proper way to access elements of a string. But it's impossible to know without knowing what `lists` is or what this code is supposed to do. Also, it's a bad idea to name your variables as `list` because that's the same as the built-in type.

Comment: The `list` contains the array of records fro the execute command as there could be multiple results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method [`fetchall()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchall.html) returns a list of tuples representing the rows, where each tuple contains the values for each column. When you did `for index, list in lists`, you are already accessing each tuple and unpacking them into `index` and `list` respectively.

I assume you have columns `'id'` and `'name'`.
If you just want to print them:

```
for index, mylist in lists:
    print("{0} - {1}".format(index, mylist))
```

or

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for row in rows
    print("{0} - {1}".format(row[0], row[1]))
```

or with f-strings:

```
rows = cursor.fetchall()

for index, mylist in rows
    print(f"{index} - {mylist}")
```

As I mentioned, it is bad to name your variables same as built-in types and methods.
**Don't use `list` as a variable name.**